# Docker - изменение данных в volumes

Tags: docker, docker-compose

Docker разработчики рекомендуют использовать volumes для хранения данных контейнера, и это хорошо работает если приложение контейнера само меняет данные.
Но ситуация когда нужно обновить код скрипта в контейнере - работает непонятно. Даже если я удаляю хранилище контейнера и создаю снова (через docker-compose) - файл копируется в хранилище не измененный. Версионность volumes как я понял тоже не поддерживается. Вариант с физическим копированием нужных файлов в /var/lib/docker/volumes/ - не совсем верный. Остается вариант только монтировать нужный каталог внутрь контейнера (как это рекомендуется для конфигурационных файлов)? Или я что то упускаю?
Заранее спасибо за ответ!

Дополнение: 
docker-compose.yml

```
version: '3.8'

services:
  server:
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: Dockerfile
    image: nodejs
    restart: unless-stopped
    environment:
      - PORT=3000
      - MYSQL_HOSTNAME=db
      - MYSQL_USERNAME=user
      - MYSQL_PASSWORD=passwd
      - MYSQL_DB=db
ports:
  - "3000:3000"

volumes:
  - server:/home/node/server
networks:
  - app-network

networks:
  app-network:
    driver: bridge

volumes:
  server:
```

Docker файл:

```
FROM node:14

WORKDIR /home/node/server

COPY ./server/package*.json ./

RUN npm install

COPY ./server ./

CMD ["node", "server.js"]
```

в текущей директории есть директория server и в ней server.js файл

Запускаю контейнер docker-compose up, смотрю что все запустилось и работает, сервер Node отдает нужные данные, останавливаю контейнер и удаляю через docker-compose down

После - копирую в директорию ./server новый файл server.js и тут пробовал такие варианты:

1. docker-compose build --force-rm --no-cache
   docker-compose up - в контейнере остается старый файл
2. останавливаю контейнер, удаляю контейнер и удаляю хранилище через docker volume rm server, стартую docker-compose up - вижу что операции копирования выполняются - но копируется все равно не измененный файл, хотя его уже нет в папке ./server
3. Делаю как в варианте 2 но создаю пустой контейнер перед запуском  docker volume create server, и запускаю docker-compose up, тут в двух случаях из 15 - файл обновляется, объяснения этому не нашел.

Comment: @RomanKonoval прошу прощения за размытый вопрос - дополнил

Comment: Докер файл используется для создания образа. А вы по ходу только пересоздаете контейнер. И вообще, используйте vcs вместо ручного копирования туда-сюда.

Comment: @user7860670 из форматирования уплыло FROM node:14, поправил. С ручным обновлением бы разобраться, vcs для одного файла который впоследствии будет обновляться возможно раз в пол года - не вижу смысл.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вы используете инструмент не по назначению, вот у вас и возникают проблемы. volume предназначены для хранения данных между запусками контейнера. Скрипт - это не данные.

Есть два канонических сценария как код попадает в контейнер:

1. во время CI - сборка образа и код добавляется в Dockerfile через COPY
2. если контейнер используется для разработки, тогда через [bind mount-ы](https://docs.docker.com/storage/bind-mounts/)

С первым все ясно - вы хотите другого. Вот демо второго способа.

```
$ cat docker-compose.yml
version: '3.8'

services:
  server:
    image: alpine:latest
    volumes:
      - ./server:/server
$ ls server
1
$ (sleep 5 && touch server/2) &
[1] 55190
$ docker-compose run  server /bin/sh -c "while true; do ls /server; sleep 1; done"
Creating 1281969-docker-volumes_server_run ... done
1
1
1  2
1  2
^C[1]+  Done                    ( sleep 5 && touch server/2 )
```

Можно конечно поместить код и в volume. Копировать данные можно с помощью `docker cp`, когда контейнер запущен (этот и или любой другой, надо только присоединить volume).

Допустим есть compose файл:

```
version: '3.8'

services:
  server:
    image: alpine:latest
    volumes:
     - server:/server

volumes:
  server:
```

Запускаем какой-нибудь контейнер и используем:

```
docker run -ti -v server:/whatever --rm --name temp alpine:latest /bin/sh
```

И теперь можно копировать файлы в volume:

```
docker cp server/server.js temp:/whatever/server.js
```

Comment: Отличный и развернутый ответ! Спасибо что прояснили непонятный для меня момент - так как docker начал осваивать только сегодня.