# как динамически получать изменения в томах в Docker на своем хосте

Tags: java, docker, docker-compose

У меня есть папка с названием 'Transfer'. В ходе работы моей программы в папке 'Transfer' могуть создаваться новые файлы.

Как мне динамически передавать все новосозданные файлы в докере на свой ПК?

Я попытался сделать как то так, но это не работает:

В файле `docker-compose.yml` для моего сервиса `transfer` я добавил том с названием `files`:

```
    transfer:
        build: ./transfer
        ports:
            - 6666:6666
        volumes:
            - ./:/files
```

`./` - папке на хосте, то есть это рядом с `docker-compose.yml`, и по моему мнению именно здесь должны появлятся новые файлы с тома под названием `files`
`/files` - том в докере

Ну и в конце `docker-compose.yml` я создал этот том `files`:

```
volumes:
  files:
```

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [Docker - изменение данных в volumes](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1281969/docker-%d0%b8%d0%b7%d0%bc%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%b8%d0%b5-%d0%b4%d0%b0%d0%bd%d0%bd%d1%8b%d1%85-%d0%b2-volumes)

Comment: @Roman-StopRUaggressioninUA, я видел тот вопрос, но он вообще не решает мою проблему

Answer (score 0):

Том files и папка /files никак не связаны и для ваших целей том вообще не нужен.

То, что вам нужно, так это:

1. примонтировать папку с хост машины в контейнер как вы сделали

```
        volumes:
            - ./:/files
```

2. указать приложению, находящемуся в контейнере, класть файлы в папку /files
3. при указанном в п.1 монтировании файлы будут появляться в папке где расположен ваш docker-compose.yml

Comment: значит нужно оставить все без изменения, только удалить ненужный том `files`, все правильно? или я чего то не понимаю? потому что сделал как вы и сказали, но файлы и дальше не появляються.

Comment: я указал приложению класть файлы в папку `files`. но забыл уточнить что этот файл лежит еще в папке с названием пользователя который этот файл туда и загрузит, имеет ли это какое то значение? или даже если файл будет в папке, то он появится около `docker-compose.yml` в своей же папке? просто сейчас это не работает

Comment: папка, указанная вами для монтирования /files а папка files лежащая в паке пользователя внутри контейнера имеет путь /home/user_name/files Тогда вам в docker-compose.yml нужно прописать правильный путь внутри контейнера после двоеточия

Comment: слева от двоеточия путь на хост машине, справа - внутри конейнера https://docs.docker.com/compose/compose-file/compose-file-v3/#volumes

Comment: а все изменения в томах должны динамически, то есть сразу же появляться на хосте?

Comment: если все сделано правильно, то да

Comment: а если у меня в папке где должны создаваться файлы в файле `Dockerfile` написана следующая строчка `COPY . /java` то может путь тогда будет не `/files` a `/java/files`?

Comment: что вы гадаете. Какой абсолютный путь к папке в контейнере куда кладет файлы приложение?