# Docker не сохраняет файлы, которые создает мое JAVA приложение

Tags: java, docker, docker-compose

Вовремя работы мое java приложение создает и сохраняет, некоторые файлы. Но после добавления некоторых изменений и ребилда (команда docker-compose up --build) они пропадают. Как сохранить их постаянно. Я пытался создать volume но он не работает.

Файлы сохраняются в корне проекта рядом с pom.xml и srс.
В логах когда сохраняю файл я вижу следющий абсуютный путь.

```
 log.info("Saved file with path absolute path: " + new File(path).getAbsolutePath());
 Saved file with path absolute path: /application/someMyFolder/fileName.json
```

### Это мой docker-compose file:

```
version: '3'

services:
  examledb:
    container_name: examle-docker-db
    image: postgres
    volumes:
      - examle-docker-db:/var/lib/postgresql/data
    ports:
      - "5555:5432"
    expose:
      - "5555"
    environment:
      - POSTGRES_PASSWORD=password
      - POSTGRES_USER=postgres
      - POSTGRES_DB=examle
      - PGDATA=/var/lib/postgresql/data/pgdata
    networks:
      - examle-docker-network
    restart: unless-stopped

  backend:
    container_name: examle-docker-backend
    build: ./backend
    volumes:
      - /var/lib/docker/volumes/example_prod_example-backend-volume/_data:/root/projects/example_PROD/backend
    ports:
      - "8080:8080"
      - "8888:8888"
    depends_on:
      - examledb
    networks:
      - examle-docker-network
    environment:
      SPRING_DATASOURCE_URL: jdbc:postgresql://examle-docker-db:5432/examle
    restart: unless-stopped

  frontend:
    container_name: examle-docker-frontend
    build: ./frontend
    restart: unless-stopped
    command: serve -s dist/vu4y-frontend -l 4200
    networks:
      - examle-docker-network

  nginx:
    image: nginx:stable
    container_name: examle-docker-nginx
    ports:
      - "80:80"
      - "443:443"
    volumes:
      - ./data/nginx:/etc/nginx/conf.d
      - ./data/certbot/conf:/etc/letsencrypt
      - ./data/certbot/www:/var/www/certbot
    depends_on:
      - frontend
      - backend
    networks:
      - examle-docker-network
    command: "/bin/sh -c 'while :; do sleep 6h & wait $${!}; nginx -s reload; done & nginx -g \"daemon off;\"'"
  certbot:
    image: certbot/certbot
    restart: unless-stopped
    volumes:
      - ./data/certbot/conf:/etc/letsencrypt
      - ./data/certbot/www:/var/www/certbot
    networks:
      - examle-docker-network
    entrypoint: "/bin/sh -c 'trap exit TERM; while :; do certbot renew; sleep 12h & wait $${!}; done;'"

volumes:
  examle-docker-db: { }

networks:
  examle-docker-network:
    driver: bridge
```

Также я пытался создать volume вот так:

```
volumes:
  - example-backend-volume:/root/projects/example_PROD/backend
...
    volumes:
      examle-docker-db: { }
      example-backend-volume:
```

Это тоже не помогло.

Comment: *"он не работает"* не является описанием проблемы. А какой смысл создавать volume для какой-то левой папки, когда файл сохраняется в `/application/someMyFolder/` - непонятно.

Comment: Тут https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/1282023/218971 рабочий пример создания файла в контейне и использования его потом снаружи.

Comment: Не работает в смысле на сохрает файлы. Приложению все так же приходиться создавть их и сохранять.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Проблему решил. Моя проблема была в том что я не понимал что нужно чтобы приложение сохраняла в указаный путь в моем случае это /root/projects/example_PROD/backend. Просто я думал что нужно указывать корень где приложение находится, а оказалось что можно указать справа любой путь и туда сохранять файлы.