# Как корректно взаимодействовать с докер и git hub?

Tags: git, docker, github, docker-compose

У меня нет опыта работы с докер, но есть опыт работы с гитом (системами контроля версий). Однако, читая документацию и просматривая видео-материалы по данной теме, возникли сразу вопросы к профессионалам этой области.

1. Объясните в двух словах, где лежат на диске файлы и папки реального проекта (контейнера) собранного из образа (образов) докера? И где лежат локальные образы докера? Как править файлы проекта (лежащего в контейнере) на докер?
2. Как сочетается подход создания веток GIT в проекте с докером? На мой взгляд одно мешает другому, трудно развивать проект по канонам гита и выкладывать потом проект на каком-нибудь hub docker.
3. Заметил, что некоторые образы не работают по отдельности. Соответственно их надо комбинировать в одном контейнере. Что будет, если разные разработчики работающие через git будут по-разному собирать образы (разные версии системы, разные технологии) и пытаться запустить один и то же проект? Возможно, что будут ошибки в проекте...

Всем, спасибо за ответы.

Comment: 1. вам может помочь https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/1189134/218971 и https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/1282023/218971. 2. отлично сочетается, независимо от схемы работы с ветками в результате у вас получаются версии приложения и вы каждую версию отмечаете тегом в докере, см. любой [официальный образ](https://hub.docker.com/_/python) - там куча тегов для разных версий. 3. вы, похоже, не разобрались в терминологии/понятиях. "комбинировать образы в одном контейнере" - это не так работает. Опишите подробней о какой проблеме речь, более конкретный пример.

Comment: @Roman-StopRUaggressioninUA, ну образ - это же программа для выполнения какой-либо задачи. Соответственно, если я хочу собрать веб-сервер, я подключаю образы apache, mysql+phpmyadmin, какой-нибудь фреймворк, например, laravel. Комбинирую их и подключаю к контейнеру. Образы могут быть разных версий, потому что это программы. Тут-то может возникнуть путаница у разработчиков работающих в команде при использовании разных образов и ошибки в коде (в системе контроля версий).

Comment: Эта проблема не относится к докеру. Если вы будете запускать программы обычным способом, то точно так же у вас может возникнуть несовместимость версий. (К вашему вопросу не относится, но вы неправильно понимаете, что такое контейнер, используете термин неправильно. "Образ"-"контейнер" находятся в таком же отношении как "бинарный файл"-"запущеный процес". Т.е. вы не подключаете образы к контейнеру, а вы создаете/запускаете контейнер(ы) из конкретного образа)

Comment: @Roman-StopRUaggressioninUA, хорошо, я понял вашу точку зрения. Однако, все равно непонятно, куда сохраняются файлы проекта контейнера, после того, как я собрал его из образов для веб-сервера, например. Я через оболочку docker for windows запустил ранее скачанный образ ларавел. В итоге образовался контейнер. Как и где я могу редактировать файлы контейнера? Под образом я понимаю программу для работы. А контейнер - виртуальная машина содержащая в себе образы-программы для работы с проектом.

Comment: Вы прочитали ответы на п. 1 выше? Там этот вопрос освещен в подробностях. "Где хранятся" - это деталь реализации, и вас, вероятно, интересует не это. Скорее ваш вопрос "как вести разработку, если приложение при зазработке рапускается в докер" или "как менять конфигурацию приложения, когда оно запускается на проде". И это там есть.

Comment: @Roman-StopRUaggressioninUA, да прочитал мельком. Скорее всего да, мой вопрос, "как вести разработку" или "как менять конфигурацию". В любом случае спасибо за ответ.